# dyld: Symbol not found: _napi_module_register

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

Had my node working with the VS Code debugger last night no problem. I haven't touched anything besides install the npm mysql package.

I come back tonight and its throwing this error:

```
Debugger listening on [::]:49952
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _napi_module_register
  Referenced from: /Users/adamsawyers/node_modules/bufferutil/prebuilds/darwin- 
 x64/node-napi.node
  Expected in: flat namespace
dyld: Symbol not found: _napi_module_register
  Referenced from: /Users/myusername/node_modules/bufferutil/prebuilds/darwin- 
 x64/node-napi.node
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

Apparently my installation of n (a node version handling package in npm) is busted somehow. My research told me that napi_module_register is part of the n package, but I'm not sure how this got messed up especially since I had it working last night.

I tried reinstalling my node packages, reinstalling n, rebuilding the project file structure, even restarting my computer. Nothing has worked so far.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently VS code doesn't like v6.10.3 of nodejs which I am running to create lambda functions in AWS (that is the version specified by AWS)

I use the N package to manage my node version. After switching to the latest version 10.7.0 as of 07/25/2018 (command: sudo n latest) and rerunning the debugger in VS code, it worked perfectly

I'm still unsure as the the cause, but hopefully others find this solution helpful

Answer (score 0):

This exact error happened to me because:

1. I needed `socket.io` to run on Node

   - Which in turn needs [`ws`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) (websockets on Node)
2. Also, I needed to run this on an outdated Node version (Node 7) for a very good reason (believe me, I would not want to do this if I wouldn't have to)
3. However, trying to use it on that old version causes above error message.

## Solution

This is a *terrible* solution, but at least I got it to work.

After some researching, I found no good solution to this. However, a close look at [the source code](https://github.com/websockets/bufferutil) shows that there is a `fallback.js` next to `index.js` which implements the same functionality as the native build but without needing a build. This will probably slow things down significantly, but at least it works:

1. `yarn add module-alias`
2. prefix your actual code with this (e.g. via `node -r fallbacks.js`):

```js
// fallbacks.js
const moduleAlias = require('module-alias');

const dependencyRoot = getDependencyRoot(); // whatever is your root folder, maybe __dirname + '..'

moduleAlias.addAlias('bufferutil', dependencyRoot + '/node_modules/bufferutil/fallback.js');
moduleAlias.addAlias('utf-8-validate', dependencyRoot + '/node_modules/utf-8-validate/fallback.js');


// run actual code here...
```

PS: In my case, in order to allow `ws` to run on Node 7, I also had to babel it, since its using modern synytax.